# How to create mock test to soft-delete void method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, http-delete

I would like to test my delete method which looks like:

```
public void deleteUser(String id) {
    var userEntity = userRepository.findById(Integer.valueOf(id))
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("Id not found"));
    if (userEntity.getLastAccessDate() == null) {
        throw new ProhibitedAccessException("Policy has been violated");
    }
    userRepository.delete(userEntity);
}
```

My delete method in repository is the following:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update UserEntity u set deleted = true where u = :userEntity")
void delete(UserEntity userEntity);
```

And I've written the following test:

```
@Test
void deleteUserTest(){
    final int id = 1;
    UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
    var idString = String.valueOf(id);
    when(userRepository.findById(id)).thenReturn(Optional.of(userEntity));
    assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () -> userService.deleteUser(idString));
}
```

This test is working good but it didn't cover the

```
userRepository.delete(userEntity);
```

Could you help me please - how can I add it to my test? Previously, I've tried to to do it through verify but it didn't help.

Comment: what do you mean with it didn't cover the `userRepository.delete`? Was it not called?
If you mean how to verify that the method was called, then what did you try to do and why did it not work (was there an error or how did the behaviour differ from your expectations)?

Comment: I mean that when I try to run test with coverage, this line is not covered. When I've used verify, I think that I've used it incorrectly and always had an error with "wanted but not invoked". That's why, I want to ask - how to test it properly?

Comment: the userRepository you use in your test is not a real object but just a mock. That means you are not testing the implementation of your userRepository, therefore it does not count as being covered in your test.
If you want to cover the code of your userRepository, you would have to write a test that uses a 'real' UserRepository, not a mock.

Comment: OK, thanks for your answer! And how can I do it? I've used UserRepository with mock annotation in order to test other methods.

Comment: You would have to create an instance of the UserRepository and pass this to your UserService instead of your mock.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get it. I already have UserRepository in my service with 'when' above

Comment: How do you create your userService? Are you using Spring and @SpringBootTest and use `@Autowired` for getting the userService-instance? In this case, you can just replace your `@Mock` annotation with `@Autowired` for your userRepository. Spring will then create a real object for you and pass this to your UserService. Note that you would then have to add test data to the database at the beginning of your test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test coverage means, which lines of your code are being called. If you mock an object, you are not calling the real code but only simulate the behaviour

Your only test the implementation of your userService and mock the behaviour of your userRepository.
So your test only covers the code inside of your userService.deleteUser(...) method, but not the code inside of your userRepository.
If you want to cover your userRepository, you have to write a test with a 'real' userRepository.